# Know of any small projects implementing an HTTP service using libevent?

Tags: c, libevent

My C is a bit rusty. I have some ideas I'd like to try and realize with libevent. Do you know any codebase I can use as a reference?

Answer (score 4):

Two good projects that have fairly straight forward code are [simplehttp](http://code.google.com/p/simplehttp/source/browse/#svn/trunk/server) and [libevent-longpolling](http://code.google.com/p/libevent-longpolling/)

Two spots i can point you to in order to answer this question in general are to search google code search for [evhttp.h](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=evhttp.h) (or a similar libevent header file) or to search code.google.com for [label:libevent](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:libevent)

Answer (score 2):

This [article](http://aleccolocco.blogspot.com/2008/10/gazillion-user-comet-server-with.html) contains example code.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few:

- http://github.com/ngerakines/barbershop -- A shifting priority queue daemon in c using libevent. Fun stuff with binary search trees and linked lists.
- http://github.com/ngerakines/johnlocke -- A torrent tracker that I'm currently working on. Very much in progress and alpha quality, but works.
- http://github.com/ngerakines/mochevent -- A libevent http service front-end to an erlang grid.